# Understanding comment from the errata about Item 41 of EMC++

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, forwarding-reference, effective-c++

In Item 41, Scott Meyers writes the following two classes:

```cpp
class Widget {
public:
  void addName(const std::string& newName)   // take lvalue;
  { names.push_back(newName); }              // copy it

  void addName(std::string&& newName)        // take rvalue;
  { names.push_back(std::move(newName)); }   // move it; ...

private:
  std::vector<std::string> names;
};
```

```cpp
class Widget {
public:
  template<typename T>                            // take lvalues
  void addName(T&& newName)                       // and rvalues;
  {                                               // copy lvalues,
    names.push_back(std::forward<T>(newName)); }  // move rvalues;
  }                                               // ...
private:
  std::vector<std::string> names;
};
```

What's written in the comments is correct, even if it doesn't mean at all that the two solutions are equivalent, and some of the differences are indeed discussed in the book.

[In the errata](https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html), however, the author comments another difference not discussed in the book:

> Another behavioral difference between (1) overloading for lvalues and rvalues and (2) a template taking a universal reference (uref) is that the lvalue overload declares its parameter `const`, while the uref approach doesn't. This means that functions invoked on the lvalue overload's parameter will always be the `const` versions, while functions invoked on the uref version's parameter will be the `const` versions only if the argument passed in is `const`. In other words, non-`const` lvalue arguments may yield different behavior in the overloading design vis-a-vis the uref design.

But I'm not sure I understand it.

Actually, writing this question I've probably understood, but I'm not writing an answer as I'm still not sure.

Probably the author is saying that when a non-`const` lvalue is passed to `addName`, `newName` is `const` in the first code, and non-`const` in the second code, which means that *if `newName` was passed to another function (or a member function was called on it), than that function would be required to take a `const` parameter (or be a `const` member function)*.

Have I interpreted correctly?

However, I don't see how this makes a difference in the specific example, since no member function is called on `newName`, <s>nor it is passed to a function which has different overloads for `const` and non-`const` parameters</s> (not exactly: [`std::vector<T>::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) has two overloads for `const T&` arguments and `T&&` arguments`, but an lvalue would still bind only to the former overload...).

Comment: O.T.: Funny, I once wrote a [similar sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d0fe04a197ed07a) for my own use (to recall when in doubt). I was uncertain whether to prefer the "const ref"/"RValue ref" pair or the template in productive work. However, there is still another essential difference: The templated version may accept more types beyond `std::string` (and you have to consider whether you like or dislike it).

Comment: @Scheff, true, but one could still insist on the templated version and limit its domain via SFINAE or a `static_assert` in the body so that it only accepts `std::string` and/or any other desired type.

Comment: What the errata is saying is that in the first example if `newName` is passed to another function it will always select the `const` overload.  In the second example, if the parameter passed in is not itself `const`, then a non-const overload will be selected in preference to a const overload.  The thing about this difference is that it would be a silent difference

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yeah, but that first _if_ in your comment is what puzzled me when I wrote the question. _If_ the body of `addName` had stuff like `newName.someMethod()`/`someFun(newName)`, then in the first example `std::string::someMethod() const {`/`someFun(const std::string&)` would be always selected while in the second case also `std::string::someMethod() {`/`someFun(std::string&)` could be selected if the argument is a non-`const` lvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second scenario, when a `const std::string` lvalue is passed to the template

```cpp
  template<typename T>
  void addName(T&& newName)
  { names.push_back(std::forward<T>(newName)); }
```

the instantiation results in the following (where I've removed the `std::forward` call as it is, in practice, a no-op)

```cpp
  void addName(const std::string& newName)
  { names.push_back(newName); }
```

whereas if a `std::string` lvalue is passed, then the resulting instance of `addName` is

```cpp
  void addName(std::string& newName)
  { names.push_back(newName); }
```

which means that ***the non-`const` version of `std::vector<>::push_back` is called***.

In the first scenario, when a `std::string` lvalue is passed to `addName`, the first overload is picked ***regardless of the `const`-ness***

```cpp
  void addName(const std::string& newName)
  { names.push_back(newName); }
```

which means that the `const` overload of `std::vector<>::push_back` is selected in both cases.